# What is $\frac d {dz} \ln (xz)$?

Tags: derivatives

I am not sure which one is the correct answer :

1. $\frac 1 {xz}$
2. $\frac 1 z$
3. $\frac 1 x$

Comment: Use the chain rule.  What is $d/du \ln u$?  Or if you prefer, $\ln{xz} = \ln x + \ln z$

Comment: So, it's going to be 1/z

Comment: Yes.  Someone has provided the answer using same approach below.  Alternatively using the chain rule you would get $\frac{1}{xz}\, \frac{d}{dz}{xz} = x \cdot \frac{1}{xz} = \frac{1}{z}$

Answer (score 0):

The chain rule would be the most general method to getting the answer for an arbitrary differentiable function of $xz$. However here we can exploit the linearity of derivatives and properties of logarithms alone.

Assuming $x$ is not a function of $z$,

$$\frac{d}{dz} \ln(xz) = \frac{d}{dz}\ln(x) + \frac{d}{dz}\ln(z) = 0 + \frac1z = \frac1z$$